# Rails 3. Scraping Google Trends for links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to get the links from this page (Google Trend). How can I do it with Rails 3?

http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly

I am quite lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, you can should Mechanize and Nokogiri. There are super screencasts on how to use them on www.railscasts.com. In case you don't know Railscasts yet, I recommend going there.

Comment: Thanks! When I try the the Nokogiri example from the video I get the error "No such file or directory - http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly". Any ideas why?

Comment: When I clicked the link, I got an error too. I guess it is because of the quotation marks at the end?!